# Declaring actions vs. expectations in GoogleMock

Tags: mocking

After reading through documentation on google mock framework, my initial impression is that ***actions*** are used to define simple functions for mock objects so that a class using those objects can be more easily tested, whereas ***expectations*** are used to actually verify correct behavior of mock objects when used by the class being tested.

The GoogleMock documentation states that actions can be specified for functions of mock objects by using the WillOnce/WillRepeatedly extensions of the EXPECT_CALL macro.  However, the documentation also states that the EXPECT_CALL macro is used for verifying expectations of the mock object after some function is executed and the mock is destructed.  So is this macro serving as two different functions, in some cases defining actions and others defining expectations?  Is there a way to set an expectation using WillOnce/WillRepeatedly instead of setting an action?  What is the difference between this and using the ON_CALL macro to define default actions?